# Passing a Custom Comparer to a Generic Create Procedure in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-10-seattle

I'm experimenting with Delphi 10 Seattle and trying to create my first Generic Container class. I need help with a Generic Comparer

Here a simple Hash object which I created:

```
type
  TsmHeap<T> = class
  private
    fList: TList<T>;
    Comparer: TComparer<T>;
    procedure GetChildren(ParentIndex: integer; var Child1, Child2: integer);
    function GetParent(ChildIndex: integer): integer;
    function GetCapacity: integer;
    function GetCount: integer;
    function MustSwap(iParent, iChild: integer): boolean;
    procedure SetCapacity(const Value: integer);
  public
    constructor Create(aComparer: TComparer<T>); overload;
    constructor Create(aComparer: TCOmparer<T>; aCapacity: integer); overload;

    destructor Destroy; override;

    //-- Methods & Functions
    function Dequeue: T;
    procedure Enqueue(Item: T);
    function IsEmpty: boolean;

    //-- Properties
    property Count: integer read GetCount;
    property Capacity: integer read GetCapacity write SetCapacity;
  end;
```

I've write the code for the methods and it compiles on its own with no problems. However when I try to create an integer version of the class I cannot get it to compile.

The problematic code is:

```
iHeap := TsmHeap<integer>.Create(TComparer<integer>.Construct(
  function(const Left, Right: integer): integer
  begin
    result := Sign(Left - Right);
  end)
);
```

This give a "E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Create' that can be called with these arguments"

What am I doing wrong? How do I create the Comparer?

Comment: `Sign` serves no purpose and is wasteful. Further, the subtraction can overflow very easily. This is wrong way to implement a comparer.

Answer (score 7):

`TComparer<T>.Construct` returns `IComparer<T>` - it is a class function and not a constructor. Just change the parameter type of `TsmHeap<T>.Create` to `IComparer<T>` and it should work.

Comment: In addition: i think that private field `Comparer` need same type `IComparer<T>`. But there is no reason to store it, because TList<T> can store comparer itself.